# Generate random nft art from characteristics

Tags: nft, random

What is the best way to generate random art from characteristics? I’m looking into creating profile picture nfts like how wicked craniums, punks and bored bananas are random. Also what is the best way to mint and distribute them on the ethereum blockchain

Comment: What do you mean "from characteristics"?

Answer (score 1):

Randomness in blockchain is a little bit tricky. I think the best way to randomness: Take a random number from chainlink and use it to whatever you need.